# shell: redirect output stream to a function while keeping access to variables

Tags: shell, subshell

I would like to redirect the output stream of a command to a function so I did this:

```
function aClassicCommand {

    sleep 1
    echo "this is logs"
}

##############################

function logsReceiver {

    read IN
    echo "received logs: $IN"
}

aClassicCommand | logsReceiver &

# doing stuff in parallel

wait
```

The problem is that the `logsReceiver` has no longer access to the external variables:

```
function aClassicCommand {

    sleep 1
    echo "this is logs"
}

##############################

var=0

function logsReceiver {

    read IN
    echo "received logs: $IN"

    # prints "in subshell var=0" and not "in subshell var=1"
    echo "in subshell var=$var"
}

aClassicCommand | logsReceiver &

var=1
echo "var=$var"

wait
```

The output is:

> var=1
>   received logs: this is logs
>   in subshell var=0

but I want this:

> var=1
>   received logs: this is logs
>   in subshell var=1

How can I solve it?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you describe a bit more about what is the exact output you are looking here ?

Comment: I've edited the post.

Comment: Why not just pass `var` as an argument to `logsReceiver`?

Comment: Because the value of `var` will change after that `logsReceiver`is called.

Answer (score 0):

You have to [export](https://ss64.com/bash/export.html) the variable:

```
export var=1
aClassicCommand | logsReceiver &
```

> Set an environment variable. Mark each name to be passed to child processes in the environment.

If it's needed to pass data into an already running subshell, it's quite complicated problem and some sort of *inter-process communication* will be needed. See for example [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132102/communication-between-multiple-processes) for details.

Comment: I've tried it an it doesn't work. Maybe because `var=1` is located after the calling of `aClassicCommand` and not before.

Comment: When a subshell is started, a new environment is created for it and environment variables are **copied** there so any changes made to the parent shell's environment after the subshell has been started are not reflected by the subshell obviously. You would probably need some interprocess communication but I have no clue if it's even possible in a shell.

Comment: Check this question, maybe it will help you: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132102/communication-between-multiple-processes

Comment: This actually seems to be the procedure to follow. I was thinking that this is trivial problem but it isn't. So I revised my plan in order to not have this kind of problem to solve. Thanks a lot anyway for the time you spent to help me.

Comment: OK, I have incorporated it into my answer. You're welcome. Glad you managed to solve your issue another way.